# multidimensional arrays and transferring buffers

Tags: c, arrays, string, debugging

I am trying to save a buffer into array segments of 1800 characters. When ever I am able to transfer the buffer over but when I try to print each new buffer out. I get null for the output. What exactly am I doing wrong?

---

EDIT - I changed the loop to this to add null terminations to the end of the 2nd dimension. now the output tell me it is null. But `printf("%c")` says the data has been transferred.

```
while(buf_pos < msg_size+1){
    if(buf_pos % 1800 == 0){
        msg_buff[key_num][cbuf_pos]='\0';
        key_num++;
        cbuf_pos=0;
        msg_buff[key_num][cbuf_pos]=buf[buf_pos];
    }else
        msg_buff[key_num][cbuf_pos]=buf[buf_pos];

    printf("%c",msg_buff[key_num][cbuf_pos]);
    cbuf_pos++;
    buf_pos++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Where are you incrementing the `cbuf_pos`, when assigning to the `msg_buff`? Also, in the `if(buf_pos % 1800 ==0)`, terminate the `msg_buff[key_num][cbuf_pos]` with a '\0' (checking that there is one more character left).

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect this to do?

```
                printf("KEY%d DATA:%.*s\n",count,msg_buff[count][0],1800);
```

`msg_buff[count][0]` is the first character of your array. You need to pass `msg_buff[count]` to print the whole string.

Also, the * modifier is defined as *The width is not specified in the format string, but as an additional integer value argument preceding the argument that has to be formatted*. I would interpret this to mean that your 3rd argument (`1800`) must precede your second argument (`msg_buff[count]`). To make things simple, make sure all of your strings are NULL-terminated and don't use the width modifier.

To actually create your array of keys, don't copy each character one by one in the loop. Use `strncpy` instead. Ensure that you have space in the buffer for the NULL-terminator (allocate 1801 bytes rather than 1800). Right now your copy loop is broken anyway, because you never increment `cbuf_pos`, so every character is written to the first position in the array.

Comment: It returns nothing . If I check the data after its been transferred like so    printf("%c",msg_buff[key_num][cbuf_pos]); it shows the data is in the variable. but how do I get it to return the full string now.. hmph

Comment: By 'return nothing', you mean there is absolutely no output from your program?

Comment: moving 1800 in front of the array doesn't do any good either, I can loop thru each elements of the 2nd dimension of the array and get the characters, but I can't return them as a full string.

Comment: OK, well, make sure that all of your strings are NULL-terminated and don't use the width modifier.

Comment: This is the input - LMTP is designed as an alternative to normal SMTP for situations where the receiving side does not have a mail queue, such as a mail storage server actingdsfds as a Mail Dery Agent. Mail queues are an inherent requisite of SMTP. In situations in which mail queues are not possible, LMTP is desirable,dasfdsf since a mail storage server should manage only its mail store without having to allocate more storage 
for a mail queue. This idfdsfs not possible with SMTP when there are multiple recipients for a mail message. SMTP can only indicate successful delivery or failure fosdfd

Comment: I just edited my answer. My advice to you is to drop this code and start over following my suggestions above.

Comment: I was looking for a function like that earlier. Thanks so much, I over looked it. I am a newb when it comes to this c stuff

Comment: but now bow do I copy bytes 1801-3200 from buf to the next array?

Comment: You still need a loop, but each time you will increment your `buf_pos` by 1800.