# Transferring buffers with multidimensional arrays

Tags: c, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [multidimensional arrays and transferring buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060438/multidimensional-arrays-and-transferring-buffers)

I am trying to save a buffer into array segments of 1800 characters. When ever I am able to transfer the buffer over but when I try to print each new buffer out. I get null for the output. What exactly am I doing wrong?

I changed the loop to this to add null terminations to the end of the 2nd dimension. now the output tell me it is null. But `printf("%c")` says the data has been transferred.

```
while(buf_pos < msg_size+1){
    if(buf_pos % 1800 == 0){
        msg_buff[key_num][cbuf_pos]='\0';
        key_num++;
        cbuf_pos=0;
        msg_buff[key_num][cbuf_pos]=buf[buf_pos];
    }else
        msg_buff[key_num][cbuf_pos]=buf[buf_pos];

    printf("%c",msg_buff[key_num][cbuf_pos]);
    cbuf_pos++;
    buf_pos++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle:

```
key_num = 0;
cbuf_pos = 0;
for (buf_pos = 0; buf_pos < msg_size+1; buf_pos++)
{
    if (buf_pos % 1800 == 0 && buf_pos > 0)
    {
        msg_buff[key_num][cbuf_pos] = '\0';
        key_num++;
        cbuf_pos = 0;
    }
    msg_buff[key_num][cbuf_pos] = buf[buf_pos];
    printf("%c", msg_buff[key_num][cbuf_pos]);
    cbuf_pos++;
}
```

Note that the modified code avoids incrementing on the first character (but only tests `buf_pos > 0` when `buf_pos % 1800` is zero, avoiding testing the obvious 1799 times out of 1800.

Without the diagnostic print, I'd write one line instead of two or three after the `if`:

```
    msg_buff[key_num][cbuf_pos++] = buf[buf_pos];
```

You could improve your diagnostic print, too, by using:

```
printf("m[%d][%d] = %c\n", key_num, cbuf_pos, msg_buf[key_num][cbuf_pos]);
```

This might highlight the trouble (though I'll grant you it quickly gets too verbose).

This doesn't really explain your problem, unless the fact that you skip to `key_num == 1` on the first pass through the loop is the trouble.